# Clang LLVM multiple version issue

Tags: c++, linker, clang, llvm

I was using gcc and totally new to clang. I had to change from gcc to clang for a certain project that required clang. I tried to install clang from the LLVM download page and had some issues. So I tried to install with apt-get since I'm using ubuntu 20.04(Both installed I guess). Now when I try to execute clang command in the terminal, I get the following error.

```
clang
: CommandLine Error: Option 'help-list' registered more than once!
LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options
```

I googled the issue and found that it's related to having **multiple version of libllvm or some kind of linker library** and the solution was explicitly specifying the version in CMAKE or whatever the build tool they are using. **But here, I want to fix the issue on my OS level, so I can use clang without any build tools**. Maybe the following will help to get a more understanding about my issue.

When I execute ,

```
apt search llvm | grep installed
```

I get the following packages.

```
clang/focal,now 1:10.0-50~exp1 amd64 [installed]
clang-10/focal,now 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libc++-7-dev/focal,now 1:7.0.1-12 amd64 [installed]
libc++1-7/focal,now 1:7.0.1-12 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libc++abi-7-dev/focal,now 1:7.0.1-12 amd64 [installed]
libc++abi1-7/focal,now 1:7.0.1-12 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libclang-common-10-dev/focal,now 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libclang-cpp10/focal,now 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libclang1-10/focal,now 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libllvm10/focal,now 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libomp-10-dev/focal,now 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libomp5-10/focal,now 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
llvm-10/focal,now 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
llvm-10-dev/focal,now 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
llvm-10-runtime/focal,now 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
llvm-10-tools/focal,now 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Any tips or way to fix this issue ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove one of the versions.

Comment: Yes, remove one, or both to start clean.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping the same but was not sure because I'm totally new to these tools and I guess some of these linker libs and other tools are by default installed with ubuntu. So was afraid to remove because of breaking other apps. Anyway removed clang installed with apt and now using clang installed with LLVM official page.Now works fine.